# JSII error while migrating from AWS CDK v1 to v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

We are currently migrating from aws cdk v1 to v2. While following the steps from the documentation, I tried to do `cdk ls` but it is resulting in the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.synth()
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site- packages/aws_cdk/__init__.py", line 16784, in synth
    return typing.cast(_CloudAssembly_c693643e, jsii.invoke(self, "synth", [options]))
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 143, in wrapped
    return _recursize_dereference(kernel, fn(kernel, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 133, in _recursize_dereference
    return _reference_map.resolve_reference(kernel, d)
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jsii/_reference_map.py", line 126, in resolve
    raise ValueError(f"Unknown type: {class_fqn}")
ValueError: Unknown type: aws-cdk-lib.cx_api.CloudAssembly
```

Here is some version info:

```
% cdk --version
2.24.1 (build 585f9ca)

% pip3 list # Showing only related packages 
aws-cdk.aws-appsync-alpha     2.10.0a0
aws-cdk.cloud-assembly-schema 2.24.1
aws-cdk.cx-api                2.24.1
aws-cdk-lib                   2.24.1
aws-cdk.region-info           2.24.1
awscli                        1.24.3
jsii                          1.59.0
```

There is no error in the code, but a conflict in the pip packages itself. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What's your `requirements.txt` file or equivalent?

Comment: @gshpychka
pyyaml
boto3
constructs>=10.0.0
aws-cdk.aws-appsync-alpha==2.10.0a0
aws-cdk.cloud-assembly-schema==2.24.1
aws-cdk.cx-api==2.24.1
aws-cdk.region-info==2.24.1
awscli==1.24.3
jsii==1.59.0
aws-cdk-lib==2.24.1
This is my requirements.txt

Comment: Try removing `aws-cdk.region-info`, `aws-cdk.cloud-assembly-schema` and `aws-cdk.cx-api` from there.

Comment: @gshpychka i removed things you said, still the exact same error.

Comment: You need to spin up a fresh virtualenv and reinstall packages from `requirements.txt`. You also don't need `awscli` in there.

Comment: @gshpychka i spinned up new venv , and it worled fine!!!!!!. Thanks for your quick response.